# Implementation of Prim's Algorithm to find minimum spanning tree

Tags: python, algorithm, graph, complexity, priority-queue

What is the time complexity of the following code? I'm implementing [Prim's Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prim's_algorithm) with adjacency matrix representation of the graph and priority queue.

```
from graph import adj_mtx, AP
import heapq as hq

lv, visited, h = float('inf'), {}, []  # O(n), lv stands for 'large_value' used to determine infinite distance, h is the heap 


def prims_mst(adj_matrix, src):
    hq.heappush(h, (0, (src, None)))  # O(logn)
    curr_dist = {item.value: lv if item.value != src else 0 for item in AP}  # curr_dist stands for current distances from the source

    while len(h) != 0:
        # print h[0]
        curr_nd = hq.heappop(h)[1][0]  # first element of the tuple is the value, second is the node  # O(1)
        visited[curr_nd] = True  # O(1)
        for nd, dst in enumerate(adj_matrix[src]):  # O(n) -> n is the number of nodes
            if nd not in visited and curr_dist[nd] > curr_dist[curr_nd] + adj_matrix[curr_nd][nd]:
                curr_dist[nd] = curr_dist[curr_nd] + adj_matrix[curr_nd][nd]
                hq.heappush(h, (curr_dist[nd], (nd, curr_nd)))  # O(logn)
        print h
```

Comment: Can't quite help with the problem, but you could make your variables more descriptive, as per [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#naming-conventions).  I mean, what is `lv` etc?

Comment: @LukaszSalitra Valid answers should go in the answer boxes below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### 1. Problem

The code in the post does not implement [Prim's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prim%27s_algorithm)! Prim's algorithm constructs a [minimum spanning tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_spanning_tree). But the code in the post does not construct a tree.

(It could certainly be *modified* to construct the tree, but you have to actually do it!)

#### 2. Analysis

The key thing to spot about the code in the post is that a node might get added to the queue more than once. This is becasue a node is added to the queue every time a new route is discovered to that node that is shorter than the previously known best route.

In particular, the \$n\$th node to be visited can be added to the queue up to \$n-1\$ times (because a new and better route might be discovered via any of the previous \$n-1\$ nodes to be visited). So the `while` loop is executed \$O(n^2)\$ times, and on each iteration of the `while` loop the inner `for` loop takes \$O(n)\$, giving a runtime of \$O(n^3)\$ overall.

But with an adjacency matrix it is possible to implement Prim's algorithm in \$O(n^2)\$ (see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prim%27s_algorithm#Time_complexity)). So you have some work to do!

#### 3. Other review points

1. There's no docstring. What does `prims_mst` do? What does it return? What arguments should I pass? I think that if you had stopped and written a docstring then you might have spotted the problem in section 1.
2. The variables `visited` and `h` are global. This means that you can only call `prims_mst` once — on the second call, the global variables have the wrong initial values. (Or else you have to remember to reset these variables, which is inconvenient and easy to forget.) It also means that the code can't be used from multiple threads.
3. Names like `nd` and `lv` and `dst` are hard to read. There is no danger of running out of vowels, so nothing will go wrong if you write `node` and `distance` instead.
4. Similarly, instead of importing a module and giving it a hard-to-read alias:

   ```
   import heapq as hq
   ```

   consider importing the names you need:

   ```
   from heapq import heappop, heappush
   ```
5. The variable `lv` is used only once, so you could just inline its value at the point of use.
6. Because the graph is given as an adjacency matrix (and because of the `enumerate` line), we know that the nodes can be labelled with consecutive integers. But the construction of `curr_dist` uses `AP` to get the nodes. It would be better to construct it in the way that you use it:

   ```
   # For each node, the shortest distance from src found so far.
   best_distance = [float('inf')] * len(adj_matrix)
   best_distance[src] = 0
   ```

   This avoids the dependency on `AP`.
7. The line:

   ```
   while len(h) != 0:
   ```

   can be simplified to:

   ```
   while h:
   ```
8. Instead of representing the set of visited nodes as a dictionary mapping nodes to `True`, use a set.
9. This line assigns a variable `dst` that is not used anywhere:

   ```
   for nd, dst in enumerate(adj_matrix[src]):
   ```

   An improvement would be to write:

   ```
   for node, distance in enumerate(adj_matrix[curr_nd]):
   ```

   and then you could use `distance` instead of `adj_matrix[curr_nd][nd]`, saving a couple of indexing operations each time.
10. The heap entries are data structures of the form:

    ```
    (distance, (node, parent))
    ```

    The code for getting data out of these entries is hard to understand because the tuple lookup `[1][0]` doesn't have any distinctive meaning:

    ```
    curr_nd = hq.heappop(h)[1][0]
    ```

    It would be better to use a [`collections.namedtuple`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple):

    ```
    HeapEntry = namedtuple('HeapEntry', 'distance node parent')
    ```

    and then you can write:

    ```
    current_node = heappop(h).node
    ```

    which is much easier to understand.